# How to filter WSUS superceded updates using UpdateScope filtering

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I'm creating a simple powershell script that reports missing updates for a certain compmputer, but although I've used some scope filtering in my report superceded updates are still appearing.

Why 'LatestRevisionApprovedUpdates' filter doesn't have any effect with the superceded updates?

```
$updatescope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope
 $updateScope.ApprovedStates = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ApprovedStates]::LatestRevisionApproved  # Includes updates whose latest revision is approved.
 $updateScope.UpdateApprovalActions = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateApprovalActions]::Install
 $updateScope.UpdateSources = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateSources]::MicrosoftUpdate;
 # $updatescope.IncludedInstallationStates=@('NotInstalled','Downloaded','Failed','InstalledPendingReboot')
 $updatescope.ExcludedInstallationStates=@('NotApplicable','Installed')
 $updatescope.ToCreationDate = (get-date).AddDays(-$days)


$mycomputer=$wsus.GetComputerTargetbyName($computername) 

$updatelist = $mycomputer.GetUpdateInstallationInfoPerUpdate($updateScope) 

  foreach ($update in $updatelist ) {
        $updateinfo=$update.Getupdate()
           [pscustomobject][Ordered]@{
            Status=$update.UpdateInstallationState
            Approval=$update.UpdateApprovalAction
            ArrivalDate=get-date $updateinfo.ArrivalDate -format dd-MMM-yyyy
            ApprovalTargetGroup=$update.GetUpdateApprovalTargetGroup().name
            Approved=$updateinfo.isapproved
            KB=$updateinfo | %{$_.KnowledgebaseArticles -join ","}
            SuperSeded=$updateinfo.IsSuperseded
            Declined=$updateinfo.IsDeclined
            Title=$updateinfo.title
          }

      }
```

In my report I already have listed 'Superceded' Updates. And I'd like to see these updates that will be installed on the target computer. 
I may add some extra filter with some "where $_.Superceded" or similar, but I'd like to understand why it doesn't work with the :LatestRevisionApproved  that I've applied on the Scope filtering?

This is a sample of a current output, what I expect is don't have SuperSeded on this list.

```
  Status     Approval ArrivalDate Approved  KB      SuperSeded Declined
  ------     -------- ----------- --------  --      ---------- --------
NotInstalled  Install 11-Dec-2018     True 4471983      False    False
NotInstalled  Install 11-Dec-2018     True 4471989       True    False
NotInstalled  Install 12-Dec-2018     True 4471320       True    False
NotInstalled  Install 12-Dec-2018     True 4471322      False    False
NotInstalled  Install 12-Dec-2018     True 4470199       True    False
NotInstalled  Install 20-Dec-2018     True 4483187       True    False
Downloaded    Install 09-Jan-2019     True 4481484      False    False
Downloaded    Install 09-Jan-2019     True 4480964      False    False
Downloaded    Install 09-Jan-2019     True 4480963      False    False
Downloaded    Install 09-Jan-2019     True 4481485      False    False
Downloaded    Install 09-Jan-2019     True 4480965      False    False
Downloaded    Install 10-Jan-2019     True 4470499      False    False
Downloaded    Install 10-Jan-2019     True 4470602      False    False
```

Comment: Hi @UhTrog! I've seen that you're active recently, but have not commented anything for my answer. Is there anything you like to get clarification about?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [`ApprovedStates Enumeration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/aa354257(v%3Dvs.85)) description on Microsoft Docs:

> ... Indicates whether or not an update is approved or declined. These
>   flags can be used to retrieve updates in the specified state. ...

The members of this enumeration are listed below:

> **Any**   -  Includes all updates, regardless of whether they are approved,
>   declined, or not approved.
>
> **Declined** - Includes updates that have been declined.
>
> **HasStaleUpdateApprovals**   - Includes updates that have an approval on a
>   revision that is not the latest revision.
>
> **LatestRevisionApproved** - Includes updates whose latest revision is
>   approved.
>
> **NotApproved**   - Includes updates that have not been approved or
>   declined.

---

Now, coming to your question as to why the superseded updates are still reflected after this condition, is because these are not supposed to check the supersedence behaviour. They are used to check the approval state (approved, declined, not approved). The latest revision is when Microsoft keeps updating/revising the update after its initial release.

If you want to determine the supersedence behaviour, the `$updateinfo.IsSuperseded` is the option to rely on.